# I am trying to create a retrofit instance inside companion object I am writing this code using using by lazy{}

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, lazy-loading

```
class RetrofitInstance {
companion object {
    private val retrofit by lazy {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build()
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }

    val api by lazy {
        retrofit.create(RickAndMortyServiceApi::class.java)
    }
} }
```

Error  message
"Type 'Lazy<TypeVariable(T)>' has no method 'getValue(RetrofitInstance.Companion, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate"

Kotlin version 1.6

[image: My code]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code snippet on my machine, and it works fine:

```html
    companion object {
        private val retrofit by lazy {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build()
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://www.google.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()
        }

        val api by lazy {
            retrofit.create(DummyClass::class.java)
        }
    }
```

So i suggest you double-check your code for typos, or you can check for dependency versions. Versions that i'm using are:

```html
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.3")
```

Comment: Can you tell me the Kotlin version you have been using in android studio?

Comment: For me It is 1.6.10